# Como puedo implementar esto en la base de datos?

Tags: sql, plsql

Buenas, esto es lo que me pide de una table emple-depart-presupuesto

Debemos asegurar que el gasto en salarios de un departamento no exceda el 50% del
presupuesto actual.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SALARIO50
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emple
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    V_SALARIO NUMBER(4);
    V_PRESUPUESTO NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(SALARIO) INTO V_SALARIO
 FROM emple 
 GROUP BY DEPT_No;
 SELECT CANTIDAD INTO V_PRESUPUESTO
 FROM PRESUPUESTO
 WHERE DEPT_NO=:NEW.DEPT_NO;
  IF V_SALARIO>V_PRESUPUESTO/2 THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20234, 'Has exedido del 50% del presupuesto de deste departamento');
END;
```

Y el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
13/4     PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo ";" cuando se esperaba uno
         de los siguientes:
         if
```

Answer (score 2):

El error está en la línea 13 en la posición 4, es decir en la línea:

```
END;
```

Y se debe a que para finalizar el bloque `IF THEN` en PL/SQL se utiliza `END IF`.  Solo agrega `IF`:

```
END IF;
```